# angular - Don't want to display a section of the main view in the routed view

Tags: angular2-routing, router-outlet

I have two sections of html in my main (app.component.html) view - one for navigation bar of buttons which navigates to child pages and the other section is to display a table of records. When select a record of the table I expect the details page of the record should display in the router-outlet but the table should be disappeared. But the details page is displaying down the table while I expect the table of records should disappear when the app is routed to a child page (details page). Any help how to achieve this would be appreciated.

here is my code:

```
<div class="navbar bg-inverse">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Home</a>
      <a routerLink="/general" routerLinkActive="active" class="navbar-brand">General</a>
      <a routerLink="/financial" routerLinkActive="active" class="navbar-brand">Financial</a>
      <a routerLink="/termsheet" routerLinkActive="active" class="navbar-brand">Term Sheet</a>
      <a routerLink="/capitalization" routerLinkActive="active" class="navbar-brand">Capitalization</a>
    </div>   
  </div>



   <!--I don't want below section of the main displaying when routed to child page  
        <h1>table of records here</h1> 

        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Thanks
yesp.

Comment: could you pls share your route.ts file?? I think your issue is , you have placed your table of records above the router-outlet. So the table will remain there no matter what route is. If you move the table to record to another component and make that component as the default view on load, i hope the issue will get solved.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of putting the table section in a separate component looks working, but the pagination logic which is moved from app.component.ts to dashboard.ts was broke and a click on next page (goes to next page but immediately within a second it's coming back to page 1 agian) is not working now. Anyway i will look into the pagination issue and get back to the board in case the issue persists. Thanks for your help!

Thanks
yesp